# Clarification on the proof of existence of square roots

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

We are to prove there exists an $a$ such that $a^2=c$ for a $c>0$.

So we define a set $S=\{x \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. }x \ge0 , x^2 < c\}$

Since $c$ could be a real number less than 1 we want to first show that $c+1$ serves as an upper bound to $S$.

Suppose $\exists x \in S$ s.t. $ x>c+1$. Then it follows $x^2 > (c+1)^2 = c^2+2c+1 > c$. But this is a contradiction to the definition of $S$ above since it defines $x^2 < c$.  Therefore this implies $c+1$ serves as an upper bound to S.

The [Completeness Axiom](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/%7Ehildebr/347.summer14/completeness.pdf) guarantees if $S$ has an upper bound then it also has a least upper bound.  Let's call the least upper bound of $S$ to be $a$.

Claim : $a^2=c$. We will first show that (case 1) $a^2 < c$ is not possible. Then we will show that (case 2) $a^2 > c$ is also not possible.  Then the only thing left is $a^2=c$

My question is why did we go through the trouble of saying $c+1$ is an upper bound of $S$ when we don't use it in the 2 cases above? I'm not seeing the connection. I know we wanted to show $c+1$ is an upper bound to $S$ because we don't know if $0 < c < 1$ in which case squaring it would yield a number smaller than $c$.  But what does this have to do with the next part of the proof?

Comment: We need to show  $S$ is bounded above to apply Completeness. We could have used $\max(1,c)$ instead.

Comment: But we already have boundedness on $S$ since $x^2<c$. Why bother taking the extra step to stay $c+1$ is another upper bound?

Comment: We want to show that $S$ is bounded above, preferably by exhibiting an explicit upper bound. Note that (as you pointed out) $x^2\lt c$ does not imply $x\lt c$, even when $x$ is positive.  After we know $S$ is bounded above, the bound we found is of no importance for the rest of the argument.

Comment: After reading your last comment above, I realized I made a mistake above.  We don't suppose $\exists x \in S $ s.t. $x^2 > c+1$ but rather $x > c+1$.  Makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: I changed $S=${${x \in \Re}$ s.t. $x \ge0 , x^2 < c$} to $S=\{x \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. }x \ge0 , x^2 < c\}$.  Note that the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ are _inside_ the math notation environment.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$